# Overriding hostname IP address in qtwebkit request

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm downloading a web page (with PyQt4/QtWebKit) using given hostname, but I would like to use a pre-defined IP address for that hostname. For example, I need to hit "http://www.mysite.com" but use the IP address 1.2.3.4 instead of the actual resolved IP address. Is this at all possible in QtWebKit? I've tried a couple things so far:

1. Hitting http://1.2.3.4/ and sending a "Host" header of "www.mysite.com". This almost works, but ends up failing for a number of reasons (I'd be happy to go into more detail here).
2. Using a global /etc/hosts setting. This didn't work because it is hard to automate and I will be doing multiple downloads at once.

Is there a way to either in python or in PyQt4/QtWebKit to override the IP address associated with a hostname?

This is big for me. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: go into more detail on #1, because it isn't clear why you don't connect to `http://1.2.3.4` directly in first place.

Comment: Sure. The core solution is to connect to the IP address directly, but send a Host header with the appropriate hostname. Problem #1: How do you handle redirects. Do you continue to send the pre-defined host header or do you follow the redirect as is? If you keep sending the same host header, I run into infinite redirect loops. With the latter, you lose the IP address you are trying to hit. Problem #2: Other DNS lookups (e.g. www.mysite.com vs. mysite.com) override the specific IP address. I realize this is complex :(

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the problem you're trying to solve?  In particular, I'm failing to see why solution #2 wouldn't work for you, it appears that you have a problem very specific with one combination of client and server.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom network access manager, something like this (C++): http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/05/qnetworkaccessmanager-tracenet-speed.html, so that you can "hijack" the network request and "redirect" it to other domain.